# Getting "The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data" error on different machine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I am running a data-driven unit test/coded UI test on with an Excel sheet using the following line of code:

```
[DataSource(
    "System.Data.Odbc",
    "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\Data.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true",
    "mySheet$",
    DataAccessMethod.Sequential),
DeploymentItem(@"Data\Data.xlsx")]
```

This works fine on my machine and my co-workers machine, but when I run on other machines, I get the following error: "The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data"

Any suggestions as to how to go about investigating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run unit tests that rely on an Excel spreadsheet on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, you need to install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Microsoft%20Access%20Database%20Engine%202010%20Redistributable). You'll need to install it on your development machines and the test machine, and change your connection string to this:

```
[DataSource(
    "System.Data.OleDb",
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Data.xlsx;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'",
    "mySheet$", 
    DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem(@"Data\Data.xlsx")]
```